# Python.NET garbage collection

Tags: python.net

I try to integrate an external C# Library in a Python project. The library reads and converts some file contents that I want to consume in Python and then delete the file:

```py
import clr
from pathlib import Path
import os
import gc

my_dll = Path('C:/MyLib') #path without .dll suffix
clr.AddReference(str(my_dll))
from MyLib import MyFileReader

file = Path('C:/myfile.txt')

reader = MyFileReader()
result = reader.Initialize(str(file))
# do something with result

del reader
clr.System.GC.Collect()
gc.collect()
os.remove(str(file)) # WinError 32 The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.
```

`MyFileReader` properly reads and returns the file contents, but I'm not able to delete the file with `os.remove` as the reader is not properly garbage collected and still holds a lock on the file. I assume the authors of the external library didn't implement the closing of the file, but I cannot check as I don't have access to the source code of the external library. How can I properly remove `MyFileReader` from memory?

Comment: Is there any close method on MyFileReader that you forgot to call before removing the file?

Comment: unfortunately not